# How do I efficiently add a filter to the 'Filter Incoming Queries' panel (for a given collection) in MongoDb App Services

Tags: mongodb, realm

I am trying to pre-filter my collections by adding a filter to the Filter Incoming Queries panel. The documentation gives a couple of examples, but I am unable to find out how I can achieve what I need.
I have a document collection that looks like this:

```
dataCollection: [
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   data: array[],
   userId: string
   metadataObjectId: ObjectId
},
{
    ...
}]
```

Next to this I have the collection of metadata objects, where I also keep the sharing settings:

```
metaDataCollection: [
 {
  _id: ObjectId
  shareWith: 
     [
       { 
        targetUserId: string, 
        metadataObjectId: ObjectId
       },
       ...
     ]
},
{
   ...
}]
```

Given this last metadata collection, I would like to pre-filter the first collection to only return my own documents (userId = my user) - this already is implemented in the owner role.

But it gets more complex if I want to check if my user exists in the sharing collection of the metadata object. So in essense, I want to add a filter that says

> return only the collection of documents where my user is in the array of targetUserIds from the metadata collection.

I first tried to do this with a different Role (sharedItems) calling a custom function. Since this was quite inefficient, it slowed down my queries when fetching a lot of documents. So the proper way seems to do this via Filter Incoming Queries, though I am not sure if this is possible.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The relationship between the objects, and the object structure itself is not clear; are you storing objects in an array of the parent object? Do you have the object structure available as it appears in your code? If so, can you include that?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for reading and thinking along! In the mean time I kept trying and think I have found the solution. I have added an incoming query filter to the data document collection like this (applying to any document):

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "userId": "%%user.id"
    },
    {
      "metadataObjectId": {
        "$in": {
          "%function": {
            "name": "getSharedMetadataObjects"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

...with the "getSharedMetadataObjects" function fetching the metadata document collection to return the ones that the current user has rights to.